# How to create an NSMenu containing an NSMenuItem which only appears while holding a keyboard modifier key?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, hidden, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I'd like to create an `NSMenu` containing an `NSMenuItem` which is hidden by default, and only appears while the user is holding a keyboard modifier key.

Basically, I'm looking for the same behaviour as the 'Library' option in the Finder's 'Go' Menu:

Without holding Option (⌥):
[image]

While holding Option (⌥):
[image]

---

I already tried installing a key listener using `[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: handler:]` to hide and unhide the `NSMenuItem` programmatically by setting it's `hidden` property. This kind of worked, but the problem is that the hiding/unhiding wouldn't work while the `NSMenu` was open. Apparently an `NSMenu` completely takes over the event processing loop while it's open, preventing the key listener from working. 
I could probably use a CGEventTap to still receive events while the `NSMenu` is open, but that seems like complete overkill.

Another thing I discovered which does a similar thing to what I want is the '[alternate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514823-alternate?language=objc)' mechanism of `NSMenu`. But I could only get it to switch out `NSMenuItems`, not hide/unhide them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that behaves perfectly!

1. On the `NSMenuItem` you want hidable, set the `alternate` property to `YES`, and set the `keyEquivalentModifierMask` property to the keyboard modifiers which you want to *unhide* the item.
2. In your `NSMenu`, *right before* the `NSMenuItem` which you want to be hideable, insert another `NSMenuItem` that has height 0.

   In Objc, you can create an `NSMenuItem` with height 0 like this:

   ```objectivec
   NSMenuItem *i = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
   i.view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
   ```

The hideable `NSMenuItem` will now be 'alternate' to the zero-height `NSMenuItem` preceding it. The zero-height item will display by default, but while you hold the keyboard modifier(s) you specified, the zero-height item will be swapped out with the hideable item. Because the zero-height item is invisible, this has the effect of unhiding the hideable item.

Comment: Clever! I was going to test using a hidden placeholder item instead of a zero-height item but didn't get around to it. Glad you figured something out.

Comment: Actually this solution has one issue: when using arrow keys to navigate the menu, you can select the zero-height item.

Comment: Maybe try setting the zero-height item's `enabled` to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, that's a good idea! But it doesn't work in my case unfortunately. All menu items seem to get re-enabled when I open the menu. Not sure if this is a quirk of NSMenu or if it's something in my code doing that.

Comment: Nevermind. After setting `autoenablesItems` to `NO` on the containing `NSPopUpButton`, this works great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your option-only menu item's action is (in Swift) `performOptionOnlyMenuItem(_:)` and its target is your `AppDelegate`.

- The first thing you need to do is make sure `AppDelegate` conforms to the `NSMenuItemValidation` protocol.
- The second thing you need to do is implement the `validateMenuItem(_:)` method, and have it check whether the menu item sends the `performOptionOnlyMenuItem(_:)` action. If so, set the item's `isHidden` property based on whether the option key is currently pressed.

If you don't need to validate any other menu items, the code can look like this:

```swift
extension AppDelegate: NSMenuItemValidation {
    func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        switch menuItem.action {
        case #selector(performOptionOnlyMenuItem(_:)):
            let flags = NSApp.currentEvent?.modifierFlags ?? []
            menuItem.isHidden = !flags.contains(.option)
            return true
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

If the action is sent to some other target, you need to implement the validation (including the protocol conformance) on that target. Each menu item is validated only by the item's target.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for your answer! This unfortunately also doesn't seem to work while the `NSMenu` is open. This is perfectly usable but it's not quite as nice as the 'Library' option in the Finder's 'Go' Menu which I'm trying to emulate. That one also reacts to user input while the `NSMenu` is open.